# ubuntu 12.04 on macbook pro 9,1. Wireless internet disconnects intermittently

Tags: 12.04, wireless, macbook

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my mac. The wireless driver is showing an erratic behavior and disconnects every now and then. Please help!

```
lspci -nn; dmesg|tail
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e57] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
01:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
03:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: LSI Corporation FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller [11c1:5901] (rev 08)
[   22.882591] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   23.907477] postgres (1203): /proc/1203/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/1203/oom_score_adj instead.
[   25.938139] wlan0: authenticate with 20:aa:4b:db:4a:24
[   25.949524] wlan0: send auth to 20:aa:4b:db:4a:24 (try 1/3)
[   25.955097] wlan0: authenticated
[   25.957258] wlan0: associate with 20:aa:4b:db:4a:24 (try 1/3)
[   25.959769] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:aa:4b:db:4a:24 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   25.960221] wlan0: associated
[   25.960656] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   27.922445] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1650) terminated with status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the have the same issue on my MacBook Air (late 2009), however I can for good sake not find the reference I found that fixed my problem.

There was an entry in /var/log/syslog that corresponded to the time that the wireless disconnected. Can you please share your /var/log/syslog?

The fix though, was to change the wireless driver, the one I'm using is
bcmwl-kernel-source:

```
$ lsmod | egrep "wl|cfg"
wl                   4207474  0 
lib80211               14352  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
cfg80211              479757  1 wl
```